# CSS Layout invalidated every 10 ms | Help to investigate

Tags: css, performance, layout, repaint

I've inherited a css file (10k lines), which I think is responsible for an insane cycle of style invalidation, recalculation, redraw. I figured this out by removing the css file from the page, which results into the disappearance of the cycle.

The file was created over time by several people, and no one is left with a full knowledge of the css content...

From the profiling attached, there's no Network activity, or JS event that could pinpoint at another root cause (such as DOM changes using JS).

In your view, what would be the best approach to find what triggers the view changes? There's no animation on the page, but I can't guarantee that there isn't one spinning on its own using an old css directive that nobody uses anymore...

The repaint causes fairly high cpu usage.

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution, but I'd remove the bottom half of the css code and check if the problem still exists.

If it is solved, you now know it is in the bottom half, if it still exists the problem is in the top half.

Keep halving the code which should contain the problem, and in about 9 iterations you can have it narrowed down to about 20 lines.